# javascript array expressions

Tags: javascript, arrays, expression

I was reading Eloquent JS and came across this code which didn't make sense to me. I wasn't able to understand it as it was explained and was hoping someone could explain to me why the second `console.log` evaluates to the value it does.

Here's the code:

```
var listOfNumbers = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11];
console.log(listOfNumbers[1]);
// → 3
console.log(listOfNumbers[1 - 1]);
// → 2
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `listOfNumbers[1 - 1]` is the same as `listOfNumbers[0]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`2` is the first number in the **zero-indexed array**

```
listOfNumbers[1 - 1] = listOfNumbers[0] = 2
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks Curt!

Comment: @MaxZoom Definitely will do. I'm waiting for the required 12 minutes to pass.

Answer (score 1):

listNumber is an array containing 2, 3, 5, 7, 11

`listNumber[0]` is `2`

`listNumber[1]` is `3`

`listNumber[2]` is `5` 
`listNumber[3]` is `7` 
`listNumber[4]` is `11`

`listNumber[1-1] => listNumber[0] => 2`

`console.log(listNumber[0]); //will print 2 at console`

Answer (score 0):

arrays are 0 indexed. so list[0] = 2, list[1] = 3

Answer (score 0):

[0] is the first element in an array. [1] is the second. Array indexes start with 0.